# How do I include iteration numbering in my output

Tags: python

Here is my problem, i am trying to add my loop iteration numbering into my output, but i cannot figure out where i am going wrong. Please keep in mind, i have looked at the similar and recommended posts for answers, and they are not similar in what i am trying to do, not to mention, i am still learning Python.

The prompt is as follows:

Write a function shampoo_instructions() with parameter num_cycles. If num_cycles is less than 1, print "Too few.". If more than 4, print "Too many.". Else, print "N : Lather and rinse." num_cycles times, where N is the cycle number, followed by "Done.".

```
Sample output with input: 2
1 : Lather and rinse.
2 : Lather and rinse.
Done.
 
Hint: Define and use a loop variable.
```

And here is my output:

```
Testing with input: 2
Output differs. See highlights below. 

Your output
Lather and rinse
Done.

Expected output
**1:**Lather and rinse.
**2 : Lather and rinse.**
Done
Test aborted
```

Here is my code that I used

```py
def shampoo_instructions(user_cycles):
    user_cycles = user_cycles + 1
        
    if user_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
        
    elif user_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
        
    else:
        print('Lather and rinse')
    
    print('Done.')

user_cycles = int(input())
shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Comment: You are not using a loop here.  One thing you need is  `print(user_cycles, : 'Lather and rinse.')`, but you'll need to add a loop.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with the code, so this does not clearly ask a single question. The most directly asked question is a common duplicate; the phrasing of the question does not make it a useful signpost.

Comment: Karl, i know there are multiple things wrong with my code, I am asking a very simple question, though. i am simply asking how to add the iteration/loop number to my output.

Comment: @AcheronParthenopaeus, there is no loop number to add because there is no loop. Have you learned about `for` loops yet? Do you see where one might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a loop to iterate through the input when its value is between 1 and 4:

```
def shampoo_instructions(user_cycles):
        
    if user_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif user_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        for i in range(1, user_cycles + 1):
            print(i,' : Lather and rinse.')
print('Done.')
user_cycles = int(input())
shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Comment: This code is not runnable

Comment: Indeed. There are indentation errors.

Comment: it's working now and it's way better for a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate your loop into a list comprehension as follows:

```
def shampoo_instructions(user_cycles):
    if user_cycles < 1:
        return ['Too few.']
    if user_cycles > 4:
        return ['Too many.']
    return [f'{n} : Lather and rinse.' for n in range(1, user_cycles+1)]

print(*shampoo_instructions(2), 'Done.', sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
1 : Lather and rinse.
2 : Lather and rinse.
Done.
```